# Git tagging and rails gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, gemfile

I have a gem that is hosted on github and not yet pushed to rubygems, and I added a tag to the master branch of the gem like this:

```
git tag -a v0.1.0 -m "gem version 0.1.0"
git push origin -tags
```

and then in a rails application I have on github I edited my gemfile like so:

```
gem 'your-gem', git: 'git://github.com/your-repo/your-gem.git', tag: 'v0.1.0'
```

My question is, when I merge in additional changes into the master branch of my gem, my rails application will still point to the last commit before I made the tag? I just want to make sure adding additional changes to the gems master branch will not break anything in the rails app. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command is `git push origin --tags`, or `git push origin v0.1.0` if you want to push just the one tag, but otherwise yes, your expectation is correct.

See here for more on bundling gems from git repositories:
http://gembundler.com/v1.3/git.html